How to find the highest marks of a range of multiple marks?
I wrote a code to give the grade and description of user given range of marks. And when the input section finished, the average of the marks is also displayed. And I want to get the highest mark of the input range of marks.
number_of_attempts = 0



repeat_until_false = True

while repeat_until_false == True:

        ask_for_marks = input("Enter marks: ")

        marks = float(ask_for_marks)



    if marks >100 or marks < 0:

            print("Invalid number! Please enter a valid number")

            continue



    total_marks += marks    

    number_of_attempts += 1         

    average = total_marks / number_of_attempts

                                                                                                                                                

    if marks < 30:

        print("Grade: W")

        print("Description: Low marks")

    elif marks < 50:

        print("Grade: S")

        print("Description: Have to work")

    elif marks < 80:

        print("Grade: B")

        print("Description: Good")

    else:

        print("Grade: A")

        print("Description: Well done")

    

    ask_to_quit = input("May I continue ? Y/N ")

    if ask_to_quit == "N":

                break   

                

print(total_marks)

print(average)

print("Thank you")



The code indentation is messed up -- there are lines at different indentation levels in the first while loop. Please fix it and get rid of all the excess blank lines.

What is the repeat_until_false for? You never reassign it. It's not needed since you use break to get out of the loop, so just use while True:

As for your question, initialize a variable highest_mark to 0 before the loop. In the loop, test if marks is higher than highest_mark. If it is, assign that to highest_mark.

Thank you very much ♥️I am a very beginner to python. Thank you

You can store all the inputs in a list, for example:
marks = []

Then use the .append() function to add the mark to the list, and then the max() function.
A possible solution can be as follows:
...
    marks.append(mark)
...

highest_score = max(marks)

print('highest score: ' + str(highest_score))

